# Подключение библиотеки jsoup к intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsoup, библиотеки

Не получается подключить библиотеку jsoup. Поиск в интернете особо не помог, проблема осталась.

Собственно, по рекомендациям из статей/видео сделал всё как полагается, но библиотека так и не появилась. Подскажите, как всё сделать правильно, чтобы начать работать с jsoup? Собственно вот что у меня имеется на данный момент:

[image]

(Подключаю без использования Maven, jar-файлы скачал соответствующие).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вкратце: измените `jsoup` на `Jsoup`.

---

Если подробнее:

Библиотека подключена правильно, о чем свидетельствует строка импорта:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
```

Если бы были проблемы с подключением библиотеки, то строка импорта была бы (частично) красного цвета.

У Вас же она серого цвета, что говорит о том, что импортируемый класс не используется.

Проблема в том, что у Вас в коде, `jsoup` – это непонятно что: такого объекта не объявлено.

Правильно будет вот так:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse("...");
```

Здесь у класса `Jsoup` (название с заглавной буквы) вызывается статический метод `parse(...)`.